# How can I change the color of code blocks in rendered markdown in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, themes

I'm creating a theme for VS Code and I've already added all the colors I wanted to customize except one. On the extensions page, a specific color I couldn't find in the official VSCode documentation https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

What is the code for this field?

In the settings.json file it would look like this:

```json
{
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
     "COLOR-CODE": "#00AA00"
   }
}
```

What would that `COLOR-CODE` be?

[image: How to change this background color of texts that are as a code block]

I already tried several codes that are available at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color but without success

I also tried calling the "Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes" tool but it doesn't work on the extensions page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is supposed to be possible by using the `textCodeBlock.background` colour customization point. See also [[theme] add text colors #26298](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26298), where the feature was requested / described.

It currently is bugged. I raised an issue ticket concerning this and suggesting how to fix it on VS Code's GitHub repo at [Code blocks in Markdown preview don't use textCodeBlock.background #179219](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179219#issue-1654746424). [A commit has been made to fix the issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/fff3860de98bc2424cfc80d6bb8d7fd94c094597). I assume the fix will be made available in the next release (VS Code 1.78).

Comment: I saw that the issue was marked as resolved, but even in the latest version it was not successfully fixed. It is a pity. Thanks anyway.

Version: 1.77.3 (system setup)
Commit: 704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710
Date: 2023-04-12T09:16:02.548Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
Sandboxed: No

Comment: @GuilhermeSaldanha the fix isn't released yet in 1.77.3. Try VS Code Insiders. Or wait for 1.78. (My original guess (1.77.2) for when the fix would be released was exactly that: a _guess_. I guessed wrong)